# laptop with Ubuntu 20 logout when left unattended

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logout

On a laptop installed with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS when left unattended for tens-of-minutes/hours, sometimes I find it logged out.
Searching around the web I found that traces of these behaviour can be found in `/var/log/auth.log`. Here is an fragment around the time where I think that the logout occurred:

```
... more of the same ...
Aug 17 13:35:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3157490]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 13:35:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3157490]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 13:45:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3158676]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 13:45:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3158676]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 13:55:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3159724]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 13:55:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3159724]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 14:03:49 <_my_user_> dbus-daemon[945]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.83" (uid=1000 pid=2383 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=940 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Aug 17 14:03:54 <_my_user_> polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:3 (system bus name :1.94, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Aug 17 14:04:31 <_my_user_> gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user <_my_user_>
Aug 17 14:04:31 <_my_user_> systemd-logind[969]: Session 3 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Aug 17 14:04:41 <_my_user_> systemd-logind[969]: Removed session 3.
Aug 17 14:05:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166501]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 14:05:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166501]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 14:15:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166529]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 14:15:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166529]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 14:17:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166534]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 14:17:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166534]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 14:25:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166554]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
... more of the same ...
Aug 17 15:30:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166698]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 15:30:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166698]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 15:35:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166711]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 15:35:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166711]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 15:45:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166743]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 17 15:45:01 <_my_user_> CRON[3166743]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 17 15:49:17 <_my_user_> gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Aug 17 15:49:17 <_my_user_> gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Aug 17 15:49:17 <_my_user_> gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user <_my_user_> by (uid=0)
Aug 17 15:49:17 <_my_user_> systemd-logind[969]: New session 2742 of user <_my_user_>.
...
```

I guess that:

- `Session 3 logged out` is the time when the system automatically closed all opened graphical session programs and logged-out
- `New session 2742 of user <_my_user_>` is the message logged when I re-logged-in (`<_my_user_>` is replaced for obvious reasons).

What is to blame for this behavior?

It does not happen often, sometimes I even leave the machine running for even a day unattended and no logout happens. Sometimes it happens in under an hour.

Comment: Just mentioning that no recent software updates were done. The update manager kicks-in once a week or so, but no update has been done in the recent days.

Comment: X session, or a console?

Comment: @TobySpeight X; whatever is default on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS